# Remove found item from array list

Tags: javascript, arrays, quote

I am building a random quote generator. I can not figure out how to remove an already shown quote from the array so it does not show up twice when the button is clicked. Any suggestions? Here is the javascript:

```
 var quoteArray = [
        {
            content: "quote 1 goes in here",
            author: "author 1"
        },
        {
            content: "quote 2 goes in here",
            author: "author 2"
        }
        ];

    var button = document.getElementById('quote-button'),
        quote = document.getElementById('quote'),
        author = document.getElementById('quote-author'),
        random;

window.onload = randomQuote;
button.addEventListener('click', randomQuote);

function randomQuote (){
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quoteArray.length);
    quote.innerHTML = quoteArray[random].content;
    author.innerHTML = '&mdash; ' + quoteArray[random].author;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can remove an item at index `i` with the splice function as such: `array.splice(i,1);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.splice(start, count)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function.

For example:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
// remove 2 in the array.
var index = 1;
array.splice(1, 1);
// array = [1, 3, 4, 5]
```